# Responsive Height?

Tags: html, css, height

I'm working on a responsive wordpress theme but I have little problem. My page includes several boxes that are displayed side by side. Each box has a responsive height and width and contains an image and text(text is overlaid on the image).

Is there a way to set all boxes to the same height considering the correct aspect ratio(image)? Also if some boxes don't contain an image?

Live-Preview: http://apu.sh/3ne

```
JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tjwHk/
```

Comment: Not really clear, sorry.

Comment: I dont see those boxes in the site. also: post your relevant markup + CSS in a JsFiddle.

Comment: is it the custom-list-element boxes you're trying to have all the same height?

Comment: @Italy This page is an overview for wordpress posts. Each box is a wordpress post and each post could or couldn't contain a featured image. I want that all boxes have the equal height as the box with the image. It's a little bit difficult to explain... :/

Comment: @avrahamcool added JsFiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion for your case is to fix all the boxes width & height to a value of your preference.

then, give a `max-width` & `max-height` of 100% to the image. causing it to never overflow the parent div [box] without losing the aspect ratio of the image. (if you'll try to do this with `width` & `height` you will lose the ratio)

**Edit:** `padding:none;` is not valid. use `padding:0;` instead

So, to summarize, change this in your **CSS:**

```
#custom-list .custom-list-element
    {
        width: 50%;
        height: 200px; /* fix any height you want*/
        float: left;
        background-color: #333333;
        text-align: center; /*so the image will always be centered in the div*/
        position: relative;
    }

        #custom-list .custom-list-element img
        {
            max-width: 100%; /* the width never overflow the div*/
            max-height: 100%; /* the height never overflow the div*/
        }
            #custom-list .custom-list-element article p
            {
                padding: 0; /* valid value */
            }

            #custom-list .custom-list-element article h1
            {
                color: #fff;
                padding: 0; /* valid value */
                font-size: 1.5em;
            }
```

and finally, because I like Fiddles so much.. http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/tjwHk/1/

Comment: thanks for your help :) I made a little sketch to show you my idea. (dev.9mango.com/preview.png) The image should fill up the whole box(considering the correct aspectio ratio) and overlaid the text, is it possible or is there a solution to set the same box height of the box with an image to a box without img? sry for my english :/

Comment: yes. using the `background-image` property. read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) about how to contain the img in the container.

Comment: but when I use the background-image property I have to set a specific height :/ In my responsive layout I use the img tag and a 100% width and auto height, the image fills up the whole box/div.

Comment: you dont have to fix a height. read cerfuly the link I gave you. also: google and read more about those attributes `background-size` & `background-position`